# How to use generic in c# to call c-functions

Tags: c#, generics

I have two functions which calls c-function inside

```
void do_double(double[] p1)
{
    // some c-function called with (double*)
}

void do_float(float[] p1)
{
    // some c-function called with (float*)
}
```

Instead of `do_float` and `do_double` I want to create some generic parameter method to call this c-functions. For example:

```
void do_generic<T>(T[] p1)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(float))
        do_float(T);
    else if ( ...double)
        do_double(T);
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Converting T to float/double does not seem to be right way.

Comment: You have a coding error.  Should be  : do_float(p1) do_double(pi);

Comment: @jdweng, yeah,thank you. It was just pseudocode

Comment: As others said, this is not a scenario for generics at all. Generics are about supporting compile time checks. And that is simply not a given, considering that you are calling C code. Last I heard, C (unlike "C with Classes" and "C++") does not even have a *concept* of classes.

Comment: At it's core, you are working with a untyped or at least weakly typed data source. In the cases where you are not sure what class to expect it comes down to either: a) A lot of overloads. b) You temporarily store the Data in a ExpandoObject. To then hopefully transalte the data into a proper C# class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical code smell scenario. This kind of type switching doesn't scale. The solution would be generalization or overloading.

Method overloading:

```
class DoSomething
{
  public void Do(double[] args)
  {
    do_double(args);
  }

  public void Do(float[] args)
  {
    do_float(args);
  }

  public void Do(int[] args)
  {
    do_int(args);
  }
}
```

Or generalization and provide an implementation that knows exactly how to handle a certain argument type:

```
interface IDoSomething<T>
{
  void Do(T[] args);
}

class DoDouble : IDoSomething<double>
{
  public void Do(double[] args)
  {
    do_double(args);
  }
}

class DoFloat : IDoSomething<float>
{
  public void Do(float[] args)
  {
    do_float(args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using generics here is wrong. You are doing a runtime check of the type inside the `do_generic` which beats the purpose of generic.

I think it's better to use method overloading. Just create two methods with the same name and different parameter type:

```
void do_generic(double[] p1) { … }

void do_generic(float[] p1) { … }
```

You have a nicer API and a compile time parameter check.

Comment: While I agree with your answer, note that this is not polymorphism, but method overloading

Comment: Regarding the edit, "runtime" is the accepted spelling; "run-time" is also acceptable.  You'll find both throughout MSDN documentation.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67013/runtime-run-time-and-run-time

Comment: @user1781290 yes, you're right. I was preparing some lessons at the same time and it got mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You effectively have 2 options:

Create an overload for each type - this keeps all checks at compile time, but has non-trivial annoyance of having to create each overload if there are many many types.

Use generics and switch on the `typeof(T)` as you currently do. This is also zero-cost, like the overloads, as the JIT will resolve these branches at JIT time for the specialised method and elide the unnecessary branches. However, this does mean that invalid types may be provided. If there is a path for an unknown `T` (which should be constrained to be `unmanaged` for marshalling reasons), then this works, else, you will have to throw some kind of exception when an invalid `T` is provided, which moves the compile-time checking of overloading to runtime, which is less than ideal